# Combine free space Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, gparted, fdisk, combine

I want to "merge" or combine a free space that i have on my main Ubuntu partition, i have tried with Gparted but i can't resize the main partition. This is the results of fdisk -l:

```
Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048    21463039    10730496   83  Linux
/dev/sda2        21465086    41940991    10237953    5  Extended
/dev/sda3        41940992   629145599   293602304   83  Linux
```

I want the sda3 to combine with the sda1, how can i do that?

Comment: Just wondering why you want to merge your BOOT partition? Boot partition should remain on it's own and read only. You only need a small BOOT partition anyways (100mb should be more than sufficient)

Comment: Then im confused on wich partition is my data, it's different if its on a virtual machine?

Comment: also important, on Boot partition not every filesystem is supported. So seperating the boot partition make sense.

Comment: Usually, the layout is like this: sda1 - boot, sda2 - swap space, sda3 - user documents and file system files

Comment: Please provide at least the output of "mount | grep /dev/sda". What are you referring to as your "main partition"? On what partition is your free space?

Comment: This is the result of the mount | grep: 
`/dev/sda1 on / type ext4 (rw,errors=remount-ro)
/dev/sda3 on /media/jesuscc29/2161bf4c-80ca-4e80-b2ae-21781242eb93 type ext4 (rw,nosuid,nodev,uhelper=udisks2)
`
And My free space is on sda3. I refer as my main partition where i have my files/documents.

Comment: As far as I know, you can not merge two partitions. You would have to shrink the sda3 as much as possible, let sda1 occupy the now free unpartitioned space and manually move the files from your sda3 (mount point /media/jesuscc29/2161bf4c-... directory contents) to sda1 (any other directory, e.g. a new folder in your home directory). If the amount of data to be moved is larger than the free space you have, you must repeat the process several times until everything is moved and sda3 is empty. Then delete sda3. But could you please edit your question first and add the output of `sudo parted -l`?